# Where does Ionide + Fake put the output executable?

Tags: f#, .net-core, f#-fake, ionide

I am trying to use .NET Core + Ionide + VS Code + Fake + Paket on macOS High Sierra.

Using the project generator, I have created a Suave application called `Test`. Ionide seems to have generated the appropriate files. After tweaking the `TargetFramework` to .NET Core, I can build successfully:

```
$ ./build.sh
...
Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.72
Finished Target: Build

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Build Time Report
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Target             Duration
------             --------
Clean              00:00:00.0026904
InstallDotNetCLI   00:00:01.2292511
Restore            00:00:04.2731055
Build              00:00:07.1234434
Total:             00:00:12.7035334
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Status:            Ok
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There are now some files in `Test/bin`, but none of them are `.exe`, which is what I would expect as output from `fsharpc`.

Where does Ionide + Fake put the output executable?

---

My project has `OutputType` executable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Test.fs" />
</ItemGroup>
<Import Project="..\.paket\Paket.Restore.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: You need to show your FAKE script.

Comment: It is the default one created by Ionide

Comment: That doesn't really help me much. You need to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Net Core compiles all projects (even executable applications) to `.dll` not `.exe` that can be run with `dotnet PATH_TO_DLL`. In the bin folder, in the subfolder for given framework target there should be file `YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.dll` that can be run with dotnet CLI.

Answer (score 1):

To generate an exe you need to supply a [run-time identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog). You can include this in the `fsproj` with
 `<PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
</PropertyGroup>`
 but you don't need to do that. You can use VSCode's [tasks.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) file to set up a build task.

My suggestion is just to run the dotnet CLI:

> dotnet build -c Release -r win10-x64

This will create an exe in the `bin\release\netcoreapp2.0\win10-x64` folder. You can also `dotnet publish` if you want a self-contained directory to deploy (this can get large).  The id for OSX will be something like `osx-x64`.

By default ionide generates an fsproj file that is targetting net461, and you might also need Fake 5 for dotnetcore. I also suggest you use `paket` in [magic-mode](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/bootstrapper.html#Magic-mode), and commit the .exe to github (if you use git).